# UWP App installed form VS Published App package does not show/play mp4 files in MediaElement

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp, mediaelement

I have added set a Media element to play a mp4 file.

*Xaml:*

```
<MediaElement Name="aniamtion" AutoPlay="False" isLooping="True"/>
```

I have set the source and played it through C#

*C#:*

```
animation.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/animation.mp4");
animation.Play();
```

This is working absolutely fine in Debug Mode and the animation shows perfectly.

However if a build a package installer and run the app from that installer, the Mediaelement shows nothing. What might be the issue here?

Comment: Any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> UWP App installed form VS Published App package does not show/play mp4 files in MediaElement

I have made sample with above, it works well for sideload package. there are some reasons cause the problem. please try to set AutoPlay as true, and check if you have packaged the media file.